Push notification from Blazor Hybrid App in Android
I've a simple Blazor Hybrid App developed in C# for Android.
I want a timer in the background, that pushs a notification every hour or so (even if the app is not open in foreground). Is such thing even possible?
All the examples I have seen so far needed a Firebase service or similar to push the notifications from outside. But I don't need that external source.
I just want to send a push notification from the app itself.

I want a timer in the background  you have to go with Background Services

You'll have to use something like SignalR or RabbitMQ if you don't want to use Firebase.

But I don't have external notification sources - the app should create the push notification by itself.

I found finally a nuget Plugin.LocalNotification https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification that can show notifications very easily.
protected void ClickNotification()
{
    var request = new NotificationRequest
    {
        NotificationId = 1337,
        Title = "TEST NOTIFICATION",
        Subtitle = "Hello! I'm a notification",
        Description = "some info ...",
        BadgeNumber = 1,
    };

    LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(request);
}

And you have to enable the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in the AndroidManifest.xml:

